# Не работают cookies при post запросе.

Tags: post, php, cookie, ajax

Cookies задаю следующим образом:

```
setCookie("test_cookie", 123, time() + 86400, "/");
```

При **post запросе**, они почему-то не работают:

```
$.post('/test.php', {
 a: 1,
 b: 2
}, function(data) {
 alert(data);
});
```

В самом test.php:

```
echo 123;
echo $_COOKIE['test_cookie'];
```

Но если перейди по адресу http://site.ru/test.php, то **cookies отображаются**. А вот если использовать post запрос, то **cookies не отображаются**.

Comment: Вы используете не пост запрос.  
jQuery.post() это удобная плюшка, основная на XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: А в ответе хоть выводит '123'?

Comment: @ReinRaus $.post использует объект XMLHttpRequest, который в свою очередь осуществляет запрос к серверу методом POST. Так что можно смело считать, что ТС использует POST запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу точно сказать, что всё работает.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['test'])) {
    var_dump($_COOKIE);

    die();
}

setCookie("test_cookie", 123, time() + 86400, "/");

?>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>

<script>
$.post('/index.php', {
        test: 1
    }, 
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
);

</script>
```